# Need Code to create ethereum wallet address

Tags: blockchain, ether, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am developing a dashboard to integrate "Ethereum" wallet, I am kinda lost, can anyone help me with the code that can generate the ether wallet to registered user?

Sincere thanks in advance. ...

Comment: Your question is too broad. Moreover, you can find this kind of information at the very first page of google, if you dare googling it ;)

Comment: I asked simple script to generate wallet address on bitcoin blockchain and ethereum blockchain... unable to get the right answer :( kindly help me ..

Comment: Sounds like you're fishing for code from someone else to solve the problem for you. The ethereum wiki might have some possible solutions for you to explore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at :

- bitcore-mnemonic
- ethereum-bip44
- ethereumjs-wallet

However, as said in the comments, this question is too broad. Try it, and come back with specific questions.